# Docusign nodejs envelopes api returns exports {}

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I'm running the following code in my nodejs server

```
  // Create the recipient view, the Signing Ceremony
  
  let viewRequest: RecipientViewRequest = {
    returnUrl: "http://localhost:3000/fund/123?state=123",
    authenticationMethod: "none",
    email: "my_email",
    userName: "Ryan",
    clientUserId: "my client user id",
    pingFrequency: "600",
    pingUrl: "http://localhost:3000"
  };

  // Call the CreateRecipientView API
  // Exceptions will be caught by the calling function

  const dsApiClient = new ApiClient();
  dsApiClient.setBasePath("https://account-d.docusign.com");

  const api = new EnvelopesApi(dsApiClient);
  const results = await api.createRecipientView(
    "1234",
    "5678",
    { recipientViewRequest: viewRequest }
  );
```

and it keeps giving me the output of `exports {}` no errors or anything. this is pretty painful to debug. has anyone else ran into a similar problem? and how did you fix it?

Comment: 1234 and 5678 the actual values you provided? 
Also, what is the recipientViewRequest? do you have the actual code you're running?

Comment: @InbarGazit no those are not the actual values.  i did not want to share my keys. will update question with the viewRequest

Comment: Can you double check that the email, userName, and clientUserId matches exactly the values you set when you created the envelope? did you create it using your own code?

Comment: @InbarGazit yup verified. i created the envelope in the UI

Comment: @InbarGazit is there any way to get more debug messages rather than just getting `exports {}`

Comment: You created the envelope in the UI? then it won't work. I'll explain below

Answer (score 1):

When you use embedded signing you must set the `clientUserId`.

But, the `clientUserId` has to be set when the envelope is created, or when the recipient is added to an a draft envelope and must match the value you later pass in a request for a recipient View.

You cannot make a request for recipient view for an envelope that was created via the web app, unless your code modified that envelope to set the `clientUserId` for the recipient you want.